# Posting XML order: Failed to retrieve query string parameters

Tags: php, xml, post, curl

I'm in the process of creating a XML file from a database. Subsequently, I am taking that XML file and attempting to post it to an exterior website. After dealing with serious issues pertaining to parsing errors, I recognized that the issue was the result of using a DOMDocument, so I converted it to simpleXML.

The error I'm receiving is:
Obj: SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [Reason] => Failed to retrieve query string parameters ) ) Reference=

```
//Save XML
$xmlDoc->save("file.xml");

//Convert DOMDocument to SimpleXML
$sxmlDoc = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
print_r($sxmlDoc);

//Posting Order XML with PHP
$PartnerNumber = '1111'; 
$PartnerReference = $row['id'];
$OrderXml = '<Order Test="true">'.$sxmlDoc.'</Order>';
$urlConn = curl_init ("https://website.com/PostXmlOrder.axd?
   PartnerNumber=".$PartnerNumber."&PartnerReference=".urlencode($PartnerReference));
curl_setopt ($urlConn, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($urlConn, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type", "text/xml"));
curl_setopt ($urlConn, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sxmlDoc);
curl_setopt ($urlConn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($urlConn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($urlConn);
if (empty($result)) {
  print "ERROR: " . curl_error($urlConn) . "\n";
  exit;
}
// Parse the response
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
echo "Obj:\r\n";
print_r($xml);
echo "Reference=";
echo $xml->attributes()->Reference;
```

The XML file is outputted to the screen in SimpleXML format. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some extra loops for nothing.

Let's review it a bit: You most likely need to POST the XML as string, so you do not need to convert the DOMDocument to SimpleXML, but just output it as string:

```
curl_setopt ($urlConn, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlDoc->saveXML());
```

See as well [`DOMDocument::saveXML()`](http://php.net/domdocument.saveXML).

Take care to *not* convert `$xmlDoc` to a `SimpleXMLElement`, so remove that code from above.

```
// Create XML String
$xml = $xmlDoc->saveXML();

// Posting Order XML with Curl
$PartnerNumber    = '1111'; 
$PartnerReference = $row['id'];

$url = sprintf(
  "https://example.com/PostXmlOrder.axd?PartnerNumber=%s&PartnerReference=%s", 
   urlencode($PartnerNumber), 
   urlencode($PartnerReference)
);

$urlConn = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array(
    $urlConn, 
    array(
        CURLOPT_POST           => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array("Content-type", "text/xml"),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $xml,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,    
   )
);


$result = curl_exec($urlConn);
if (empty($result)) {
  print "ERROR: " . curl_error($urlConn) . "\n";
  exit;
}

// Parse the response
$sxml = simplexml_load_string($result);

echo "Obj:\r\n", print_r($sxml);
echo "Reference=", $sxml->attributes()->Reference;
```

Comment: Thanks Hakre.  I see now there was no reason to convert the DOMDocument to SimpleXML, as I can use the saveXML() function to output the string.  Unfortunately my problem persists, but it appears that the issue involves the posting format.

Comment: Yes, that *can* be. If you see the longer example, I changed that, too, and put it to an `$xml` variable at first so it's more easy to debug. you can `echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars($xml); die;` then to verify if the concrete XML matches your expectations.